# Indexerror in nested ifs using python

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing

running a program I am making to draw with turtle graphics, I put in an exit command, however now whenever I enter any single-word commands I get an indexerror (IndexError: list index out of range) at the elif for the "back" command:

```
def parse_line(line):
    global items_in_line
    items_in_line = line.split(" ",1)
    if items_in_line[0] == "forward":
        if isinstance(items_in_line[1], int):
                return items_in_line
    elif items_in_line[0] == "back" or "backward":
        if isinstance(items_in_line[1], int):
             return items_in_line
    ...
    elif items_in_line[0] == "exit":
        sys.exit()

line=input("Enter a turtle command or enter 'file' to load commands from a file")

x = parse_line(line)
```

Why? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Note that changing the last else to elif as you did will also not solve the issue. As the check will not reach it. You need to change the 2nd elif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elif items_in_line[0] == "back" or "backward":
```

the above condition is equivalent to: -

```
elif (items_in_line[0] == "back") or "backward":
```

Which will always be evaluated to true, and thus will also be executed if you pass "exit" as input, and hence `items_in_line[1]` will throw `IndexError`.

You need to change the condition to: -

```
elif items_in_line[0] in ("back", "backward"):
```

Comment: @user1879595. See my comment on your change. It will not solve your issue by change the last else to elif.

Answer (score 0):

That `elif` should read:

```
elif items_in_line[0] in ("back", "backward"):
```

Your current version is interpreted as

```
elif (items_in_line[0] == "back") or bool("backward"):
```

which always evaluates to `True`, since `bool("backward")` is `True`.